# Tor for confidentiality on corporate network

Tags: tor, tls-intercept

I work in gov organization and recently I learned they set up a MITM, by installing some certificates - so when I visit any web site and then check the certificate info it shows the certificate installed by my organization.

My question is, will using Tor, protect me in such scenario, e.g. if I visit Facebook, will my password leak?

---

Just update based on some answer, if this info is more useful in terms of detecting if Tor works in my case:

- The certificate presented by Facebook using Tor looks legitimate, which is not the case with Chrome.
- Using Tor, I managed to successfully log in to Facebook. Attempt wasn't blocked by Tor.

Comment: I presume that you are also using government supplied computing resources? Keep in mind that it's entirely possible that monitoring software is running on your workstation. This could provide full access to everything you do and encryption or tunnels will not make a difference.

Answer (score 2):

This kind of MITM is common in large organization where security is a concern because it is the condition for [Deep Packet Inspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_packet_inspection). Said differently your organization has decided that as you are using their machines and their data they want to control what is exchanged and with who. Most of the time, *common* private use is accepted and neither the security team no your manager actively spies on your logs, unless you switch a red light on by accessing *poor reputation sites* or having *abnormal* volumes.

Now for your question:

> will using Tor, protect me ?

Probably, *provided* you can use it. To access the first Tor relay, you will have to go through the corporate proxy, which will try to apply its MITM attack. The most probable result is that the Tor client will detect the attack and abort the connection. So your password will not be leaked, but simply because you will not be able to connect to Facebook via Tor.

**But** there is a much more serious problem. In many organizations, using Tor is explicitly forbidden or restricted to special use cases via the internal security policies(*). Breaking them is then a professional fault with all the involved possible outcomes. Even it is not forbidden, it could trigger security alarms, and the security team will actively control what you are doing.

So IMHO the good question is *should I use Tor in such a scenario?* and the answer is "no". Better to refrain and use your smartphone to access Facebook.

---

(*) Even if in most countries your privacy even at work is protected by laws, many security officers think that there are few legitimate use cases for Tor in a professional context. And using your personal Facebook access from the corporate network is definitely not one...

Comment: Am I correct to deduce from your answer that if I managed to successfully log into FB using Tor (and it didn't block me), then my pwd was probably protected?

Comment: @daveBeginner: If you could control that you got the correct server certificate and not the fake one from the MITM attack at the corporate proxy, then yes your passwd has not been intercepted.

Comment: I still have a feeling this answer doesn't answer the question technically: according to this image: https://images.theconversation.com/files/158813/original/image-20170228-13104-ylxylj.png?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=754&h=400&fit=crop&dpr=1, one would think anything going out from me including password would be encrypted (green line), isn't it?